Angular17 Jest testing: RuntimeError: NG05104: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
I have an application on Angular 17. It builds and runs without errors. But during the implementation of unit tests (Jest), when testing one of the components, an error occurs
RuntimeError: NG05104: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements

jest.config.ts:
 // @ts-ignore
globalThis.ngJest = {
  skipNgcc: true,
  tsconfig: "tsconfig.spec.json", // this is the project root tsconfig
};

/** @type {import('@jest/types').Config.InitialOptions} */
export default {
  preset: "jest-preset-angular",
  testEnvironment: "@happy-dom/jest-environment",
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/src/setup.jest.ts"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$": [
      "jest-preset-angular",
      {
        tsconfig: "<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json",
        stringifyContentPathRegex: "\\.(html|svg)$",
        isolatedModules: true,
        useESM: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  globalSetup: "jest-preset-angular/global-setup",
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)",
    "/node_modules/?!@angular",
  ],
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src"],
  fakeTimers: {
    enableGlobally: true,
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@src/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
    "^@models/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/app/models/$1",
    "^@directives/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/app/directives/$1",
    uuid: require.resolve("uuid"),
  },
};

libraries versions:

primeng: 17.18.10
jest: 29.7.0
@types/jest: 29.5.13
jest-preset-angular: 14.2.4
happy-dom: 15.7.3
ts-node: 10.9.2

The component has a lot of injections, maybe this cause an error?
    private readonly someApiService = inject(SomeApiService);
    private readonly destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);
    private readonly anotherService = inject(AnotherService);
    private readonly formBuilder = inject(FormBuilder);
    private readonly changeDetectorRef = inject(ChangeDetectorRef);

test spec.ts file:
describe('SomeComponent', () => {
    let component: SomeComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<SomeComponent>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [SomeComponent, HttpClientTestingModule, BASE_API_URL],
            providers: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});

tsconfig.spec.json:
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./target/dist/out-tsc/spec",
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "files": ["src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}

Everything OK with my app-root selector, there is AppComponent with 'app-root' selector.
What could have caused this error and how can it be fixed?

Why is HttpClientTestingModule in both the imports and providers? It should be only in imports. Also what is BASE_API_URL and is it really to be imported, or do you need to move it to providers? Please share tsconfig.spec.json as well.

Yes, fair point. Moved those HttpClientTestingModule and BASE_API_URL ​​to providers (and error is still exist). Also added tsconfig.spec.json to original post
